# What is tested by IcuTest?

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, gui

In the current ["Automated Software Testing" magazine](http://www.automatedtestinginstitute.com/home/ASTMagazine/2012/AutomatedSoftwareTestingMagazine_November2012.pdf) there is a short article about [IcuTest](http://icutest.com/icu/). It is written that with "Test Generator" you can automatically create GUI unit tests:

> ICUTest is a free GUI Unit test tool for Windows Presentation
>   Foundation. Test Generator, included with ICUTest,  is a tool that
>   automatically creates GUI unit tests for an application. Just specify
>   your assembly (executable or DLL) and Test Generator will  inspect
>   your assembly for UI components and generate unit tests automatically.

1. What is the benefit of such tests, what is tested? Is it a bitmap comparison that is recorded when you execute Test Generator for the first time and which wants to make sure the layout does not change? If yes, it could be a useful tool to see whenever some (unexpected) changes to the GUI were made. Am I right?
2. Is anyone using this tool in production environment?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Quick start guide](http://icutest.com/icu/quick_start.aspx) the principle method used in generating the test code is CheckView(). Which compares two png screenshots of a screen a before and after then throws an exception if there are any differences. In the background it does this with some unit testing code:

```
static IcuTest ICU = IcuTestStarter.IcuFromDir(@"c:\test_data");

[TestMethod]
public void TestMyWindow()
{
    ICU.Invoke(() => {
        var w = new MyWindow();
        w.Show();
        ICU.CheckView(w, "MyWindowTest");
        w.Close();
    });
}
```

We don't use this tool in production, but it seems to me to just be a proprietary unit testing framework specialized for UI work - with the main aim to avoid threading issues. Maybe have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340/how-to-test-a-wpf-user-interface) for a open source solution you can modify and build on. As I would be worried about this auto generated method misinterpreting my screens (although maybe someone with more expertise on this product could provide more information - I could be wrong).